# sed on a file equate to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, sed

here's my shell commands:

```
  temp=`cat ./myFile.xml`
  perry=`$(echo "$temp"| sed -n 's:.*<myTag>\(.*\)</myTag>.*:\1:p')`
  echo "$perry"
```

unfortunately, the 'perry' variable never prints, it just prints a blank line, what's going on here?

example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="foo" xmlns:xsi="bar"
         xsi:schemaLocation="foo">
  <myTag>
   .... several tags inside...
  </myTag>
</project>
```

my final goal, is to capture everything between  from the standard xml file and then run an 'awk' command on it to replace certain parts (after incrementing version numbers), just fyi.

Thank you!

Comment: An example of the data in the xml file would be good

Answer (score 1):

You're using both backticks and `$()` to execute the commands in the second assignment. Both of them execute the contained command and substitute it back into the command line. So the result of `sed` is being taken as a command to execute, and the output of that is being put into `perry`. Since the contents of the tag is presumably not a valid command, the second execution gets an error.

Get out of the habit of using backticks in shell, and just use `$()`.

```
temp=$(cat ./myFile.xml)
perry=$(echo "$temp"| sed -n 's:.*<myTag>\(.*\)</myTag>.*:\1:p')
echo "$perry"
```

However, this will only work if `<myTag>` and `</myTag>` are on the same line, since `sed` operates one line at a time. So it won't work with the example file you posted in the question (I wrote the above answer before you added that).
A better tool for extracting data from XML files is [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It doesn't work. The perry variable never gets printed. I'm running this in a terminal on a mac. Could it be an OS issue?
However, if I do straight up echo `cat ./myFile.xml` | <the sed command>, it prints just fine. :|

Comment: You don't have `<myTag>` and `</myTag>` on the same line in your file. `sed` operates one line at a time, so there's no line that matches the regexp.

Comment: If you want to parse XML in a shell script, I suggest you install `xmlstarlet`.

Comment: I just checked if the var is empty or not, and it seems that it's empty, not sure what's happening.

Comment: @ParikksitBhisay I just told you. Your `sed` command will only work if `<myTag>` and `</myTag>` are on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use awk later on, use it from the start:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /<myTag>/) {strt=1} if (strt==1) {print $0} if ($0 ~ /<\/myTag>/) {strt=0} }' myfile.xml
```

Each line is pattern matched against "" if it is matched, we begin set strt=1 and begin printing the text. If "" is pattern matched, we set strt=0 and stop printing.

You can add to the script to change tags.